# JFileChooser java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

In a Java Swing application, sometimes the error below occurs:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.convertRowIndexToModel(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.FilePane$SortableListModel.getElementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.getSelectedValue(Unknown Source)
```

It happens when the user browses directories using the JFileChooser. The exception is printed to the output consolle , but it seems that it does not cause any apparent problem. I can't reproduce this error, but it occurs on customers' machines. Can I ignore  this exception? Could it cause some other hidden malfunctions?

The complete stack trace is below.

Java version is 1.8.0_45.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.convertRowIndexToModel(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.FilePane$SortableListModel.getElementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.getSelectedValue(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI$Handler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.showDialog(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue right now with java 1.8.0_b144

Answer (score 2):

Its a bug in Java: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6684952
Ask the customer to use a newer version of java.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are using Java 1.8.0_45 and that bug is fixed for such version.